# Cannot resolve services with service name inside a kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, networking

I cannot access a pod from another pod with its service name. Getting error as

> cannot resolve host `svcname`

When i try to view the information of /etc/resolv.conf, i do see ec2.internal as searches and ndots as 1. What does this means and how do i solve this to access a pod from another pod with the service name.

Comment: can you show us the URL format you trying to reach? are you using `.local`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `/etc/resolve.conf` should include `search <currentnamespace>.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local` to discover hostnames that aren't FQDN.

As an example, this is the content of my pod's `/etc/resolve.conf`:

```
nameserver 10.100.0.10
search staging.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

With this configuration, DNS resolution works like this:

1. Is the hostname a fully qualified domain name (FQDN)? (In other words, does it end with a dot, like "google.com.")
2. If it's an FQDN, query nameserver (`10.100.0.10`) for the hostname.
3. If it's not an FQDN, then append the **1st** element of the config **search** to the hostname. `svcname` -> `svcname.staging.svc.cluster.local` and query the nameserver.
4. If no results found, try to append the **2nd** element of the config **search** to the hostname and query the nameserver.
5. ...

You want to resolve the hostname `svcname` but its FQDN is `svcname.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local.` and you need that **search** configuration to convert it to FQDN.